# Variables addresses in C

Tags: c, windows, winapi

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
    char *dd,aaa[500];
    strcpy(aaa,"test 1");
    dd=aaa;
    printf("1. %s\n",dd);
    strcpy(aaa,"test 2");
    printf("2. %s\n",dd);


system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

When i have changed `aaa` variable by `test 2` string, `dd` also changes, why?

Comment: What you are asking is not clear. Could you post the **exact** code you are using ?

Comment: I have added comments to my code...

Comment: Your writing is quite unclear. When you say a pointer "changed", you're **not** saying whether the pointer itself changed, or the value pointed to by that pointer changed. This is why you need to provide a better example than this `someFunc(some params)` nonsense.

Comment: I changed question text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be great if you said what you are trying to do in order for others to put your code into perspective.

Now you seem to have not understood well how pointers work. Since your code isn't really easy to read, the answer will be general.

Pointers 'hold' addresses to memory. If you have pointer `ptr1` pointing towards memory block `A` and pointer `ptr2` pointing towards `ptr1`, if you change `ptr1`, naturally `ptr2` will experience the same changes. In your first block of code, you seem not to understand why `someVar` changes after `otherVar` changes. To make more explicit what @dmp has pointed out, you have told you program ( the operating system is managing memory for your program ) that `someVar` will point towards the value held in `otherVar[0]`. Now when `otherVar[0]` changes, `someVar` will change because that is how pointers are supposed to work, it is called to dereference a pointer - when you request the value of what the pointer points to - and you'll notice that things changed pr `ptr2`. So, please reread about pointers again.

In your second block of code, I don't know what you trying to accomplish but whatever it is, it will `SEGFAULT`. That is so because again, you haven't understood the relationship between pointers, arrays and how dynamic memory allocation works. For example, in the `splittext` function you have this line:

`wchar_t *arr[2],*loc = wcsstr(stri, del), buf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];`

Right there: you telling the operating system to check the value at the 3rd cell of `*arr` while you haven't allocated memory for it. Also, when allocating memory, remember:

1. If you want to allocate memory for `char` to get a string your pointer will have to be a pointer towards `char` like this:

`char* my_string = malloc( 256*sizeof(char))`

Now you want to get memory allocated to pointers towards say  variables of type `FILE*`.
If you write `FILE** my_files = malloc( NUMBER_OF_FILES*sizeof(FILE))` it will get you into trouble. Rather write :

`FILE** my_files = malloc( NUMBER_OF_FILES*sizeof(FILE*))`

This is with regards to how you allocated memory for say `arr`.

1. Also don't cast the return value of `malloc`. It will hide many errors the compiler could have caught!

To sum up, first try to learn about pointers before moving on to a bit advanced uses of pointers, arrays and memory allocation; second you can't put incorrect code ( you will know it is incorrect either it doesn't compile or just crash ) and tell others : "hey look at that variable, that is where my problem is." Try to do more research into the question, try learning what tools can assist - a debugger in this case - and that will be improve the quality of your question. Third and last, if English is not your first language, you can mention it and others will be willing to assist in reformulating your question.

Hope you will do better next time!

**UPDATE**

After edit by OP, the question now is clearer and the OP's problem is about pointers.

`dd`'s value changes because:

`aaa` is a pointer like this: `char aaa[500]` is equivalent to `char* aaa = malloc(500*sizeof(char))`. Now when you `dd=aaa`, you told the compiler that `dd` will point to the same memory address as does `aaa`. So every time you modify `aaa` `dd` gets modified because they point to the same thing in memory.

If that wasn't clear, try to reread the definition of a pointer.

Comment: I can't understand yet pointers and datatypes  in C and this is my big problem. I have one question if you can answer , char *var; and char var[50];  what is  difference?   i can put string in  *var and in var[50] too. How are at this moment allocated memory for var variable

Comment: When you write `char var[50]` you are telling the compiler to allocate 50 memory cells for your variable. If you use less than that, the rest will be unused. If you use more, there will be an overflow. But if you write `char* var` you need now to tell the compiler how much memory you want `var` to point to by doing memory allocation. Arrays are pointers as a consequences. `char var[50]` is equivalent to `char* var = malloc(50*sizeof(char))`.

Comment: But when i have char *var; i still can put small string for example var="test"; if for this variable is not yet allocated memory,  where  "test" string is saved? 

Sorry for many questions,  sometimes i think i understand, but  turns out that I do not understand.

Comment: That might happen but it is independent of the C language. The behavior of a program containing such code will be undefined. Ask yourself: i learnt this isn't supposed to happen, why is it? Do more tests with the right code and the wrong code. You'll notice that you can't predict every time how the wrong code will behave. No problem asking questions, just also try to make some efforts. It will encourage every one else. If you are new to online communities, read the next on [here](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) it will help reduce down votes for your questions.

Comment: Ok, thanks for reply :) finally i solved my problem by allocating memory `wchar_t *currtime;` and now this have it's own memory and not takes from another variable.

Comment: if you have the correct program now, update your post to ask if you've done things right now. if others say yes, make it an answer then accept it.

Comment: I had changed code. And now in my opinion, this is clean code and anyone can see what was problem :D

Comment: Thank you, you helped me to understand somethings about pointers.

Comment: Glad i could help! :) best wishes!

Answer (score 0):

What you ask is not clear, however, pointers in C are passed by value (there is a copy of the pointer pointing to the same location).  If you dereference a pointer and change the value pointed to, the caller will see the change.

Answer (score 0):

A quick pointer lesson should clear it up:

What happens on this line?
char *dd = aaa;

You've created a pointer to a character allocation called dd and pointed it to the memory address that aaa is stored at.

aaa's address is on the stack and static (you created it implicitly with your aaa[500]).

Now, when you put data into aaa, aaa's location in memory does not change, simply the data stored at that position in memory.  When you try to print out the 'contents' of aaa, you're getting the characters stored at that point in memory.  When you copy new data into aaa, the position in memory still remains the same, and thus dd is still pointing to the same memory space as aaa does.

My apologies if that's no clearer than anyone else's...